# pyinstaller py to exe missing kivy module

Tags: python, kivy, exe

so in short, my problem is when I convert my the stuff I have into a single file, even tried auto py to exe yet I kept getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

I dont know how to fix this I've looked to alot of tutorials, I tried alot of things and it still didnt work,

[here is my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5vwj.png) so yeah its quite weird please help I dont know how to fix this I tried hidden import on auto py to exe, I tried reading thru the help stuff in advanced settings, I tried alot of stuff and it didnt work

as more clarification, I've been watching a tutorial on "tech with tim" on how to do that and entered the exact commands in the video, kivy module is highly used in the script, the error is up there and it still didnt work after alot of attempts

Comment: Did you have the project environment active when you ran PyInstaller? How did you run PyInstaller, exactly?

Comment: from the CMD, I believe I had PATH on with python, idk if kivy can be like inside PATH though, I want to make the code converted to exe and tuff so I can send it to my friend

Comment: as more clarification, I've been watching a tutorial on "tech with tim" on how to do that

Comment: "from the CMD"—what is the exact command you ran? "I believe I had PATH on with python, idk if kivy can be like inside PATH though"—are you using a virtual environment? Make sure you can run `python main.py` successfully from the terminal first. If you can, you should be able to run PyInstaller on it. It would be helpful to see your `main.py`, or at least a [mre] version. Please [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: @Chris sorry for not replying for a bit I had stuff to do, I dont know how to reply to that but I believe it should be more clarified now, the video is from youtube and yeah

Comment: hell I didnt see add the code part but dont worry will do after I'm finished with something